# General solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{t}{1+t^2}y=1-\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}y$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution:

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{t}{1+t^2}y=1-\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}y$$

We are currently learning about non homogeneous differential equations and the standard form we are given is:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=b(t)$$

with that being said, the right hand side must be in the form with respect to t. So then I decided to minus 1 and divide by -y and obtain:

$$-\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}$$

However, now it still doesn't look like the standard form because $\frac{dy}{dt}$ has -$\frac{1}{y}$. So how would I proceed upon this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the $y$ on the right side? Usually this is the place for the inhomogeneity that only depends on $t$, contains no further $y$.

Comment: My professor said this is a trick question. So yes, I'm sure he wanted us to manipulate this equation in some way.

Comment: The "trick" of the "trick question" could also be that the coefficients are all logarithmic derivatives so that you do not need any partial fraction decompositions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about moving both of the terms with a $y$ to the same side and then factoring the $y$? I.e. what about
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + \left(\frac{t}{1+t^2} + \frac{t^3}{1 + t^4}\right) y = 1
$$

Comment: Yes! that was brilliant. My glasses couldn't even help me notice that haha.

Comment: Is there any way to solve that ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes - I would use the method of an integrating factor (multiply through by $e^{\int_0^t \left( \frac{t}{1+t^2} + \frac{t^3}{1 + t^4} \right)}$ on both sides, write the left hand side as a total derivative and then use the FTC to find the solution. I'm unsure there will be a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @DanZimm. I really would like to see ! I tried and I am fully stuck. Thanks for your answer and comment.